# Adding reference to regular class library in portal class library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, portable-class-library

I currently have a project which relies on portable class libraries, I need a data access layer however for which I'm using a repository pattern and fluent api. I tried to use a portable class library to implement this but found out that PCL's do not support System.Data.Entity.

I now have a regular class library and am trying to reference it from a portable class library. I manually added the reference to the Regular library DLL but this has not worked. Does anybody know of any work arounds to this problem or any alternatives?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The project you are using the class library in must also support it. If you place the code from the PCL in the class library and reference this in your main project it should work. On what platform are you using the PCL?

Comment: It's using .net4.6 and Windows 10.0 univeral. See my main project is the portable library as I am running a simulation which is using a game engine called Xenko. This automatically creates a PCL as the game project. I have another project in the solution which is a DAL, I need to somehow connect this DAL to the game project. Does that make sense?